# Is there any universal way to detect if android device is TV dongle or STB?

Tags: android

I tried to list all features with following code:

```
features = "";
final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
final FeatureInfo[] featuresList = packageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
for (FeatureInfo f : featuresList) {
    features += f.name + "\n";
}
```

I get following result on TV dongle:

```
android.hardware.wifi 
android.settings.battery
android.hardware.location.network
com.google.android.feature.GOOGLE_BUILD 
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch
android.hardware.screen.landscape 
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.faketouch 
android.hardware.camera
android.software.pppoe 
android.hardware.usb.accessory
android.hardware.microphone 
android.hardware.location.gps
android.settings.location 
android.hardware.ethernet
android.hardware.camera.autofocus 
android.hardware.camera.front
android.software.live_wallpaper 
android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer
android.hardware.touchscreen 
android.hardware.camera.flash
```

TV dongle not have half of this features like camera, touchscreen, accelerometer and so on.
It's like every manufacture can fake this features at his own free will. 
Is there any universal way to detect if device is dongle or STB and forbid my application for that kind of devices to not see and can't install via Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any universal way to detect if device is dongle or STB and forbid my application for that kind of devices to not see and can't install via Google Play?

I am not aware of any "TV dongle" devices that legitimately have the Play Store on them, though it is possible that there are some out there. In the case of a "TV dongle", some offer "faketouch", which for them usually means "let the mouse pretend to be a finger".

You are welcome to state that your app needs some degree of multitouch via `<uses-feature>`, which may weed out faketouch devices. However, particularly for device manufacturers that pirate the Play Store, there is nothing you can do to "universally" ensure that a device does not lie about its feature set.